# Having problem in data mapping in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are currently building an e-commerce website using react-redux. We use mock JSON data in order to develop the product and category page using JSON-server. But While changing the data with real data. then we have a problem with typeError: item.variant is undefined.

Anyone help to solve this problem.

**mock data:**

```
{
  "product": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Flare Dress",
      "price": 120,
      "salePrice": 200,
      "discount": 50,
      "pictures": [
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/21.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/36.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/12.jpg"
      ],
      "shortDetails": "Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem,",
      "description": {
        "Ram": "4gb",
        "size": "large"
      },
      "stock": 16,
      "new": true,
      "sale": true,
      "colors": ["yellow", "gray", "green"],
      "size": ["M", "L", "XL"],
      "tags": ["nike", "caprese"],
      "rating": 4,
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "yellow",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "gray",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/21.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "green",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/36.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Wrap Dress",
      "price": 330.0,
      "salePrice": 165.0,
      "discount": 50,
      "pictures": [
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/15.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/7.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/9.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/13.jpg"
      ],
      "shortDetails": "unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem,",
      "description": {
        "Ram": "4gb",
        "type": "personal",
        "hacker": "world",
        "size": "extralarge"
      },
      "stock": 6,
      "new": true,
      "sale": false,
      "category": "women",
      "colors": ["gray", "orange"],
      "size": ["M", "L", "XL"],
      "tags": ["caprese", "puma"],
      "rating": 5,
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "gray",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/15.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "orange",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/7.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Danim Jeans",
      "price": 500.0,
      "salePrice": 250.0,
      "discount": 50,
      "pictures": [
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/32.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/2.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/25.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/26.jpg"
      ],
      "shortDetails": "Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem,",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
      "stock": 12,
      "new": false,
      "sale": false,
      "category": "women",
      "colors": ["blue", "white", "yellow"],
      "size": ["M", "L", "XL"],
      "tags": ["puma"],
      "rating": 4,
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "blue",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/32.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "white",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/2.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "yellow",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/25.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Waist Dress",
      "price": 180.0,
      "salePrice": 360.0,
      "discount": 50,
      "pictures": [
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/5.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/12.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/31.jpg",
        "/assets/images/fashion/product/18.jpg"
      ],
      "shortDetails": "Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem,",
      "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
      "stock": 10,
      "new": true,
      "sale": true,
      "category": "women",
      "colors": ["pink", "gray", "green"],
      "size": ["M", "L", "XL"],
      "tags": ["lifestyle"],
      "rating": 4,
      "variants": [
        {
          "color": "pink",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/5.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "gray",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/12.jpg"
        },
        {
          "color": "green",
          "images": "/assets/images/fashion/product/31.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**real data:**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "active": true,
      "slug": "try",
      "sku": "009993",
      "name": "Samsung s10",
      "price": 220.0,
      "effective_price": 234.0,
      "price_unit": "US Dollar",
      "unit": "pieces",
      "short_description": "My phone",
      "description": "Samsung phone new brand.",
      "for_sale": false,
      "for_sale_percent": 0.0,
      "for_sale_price": 0.0,
      "creation_date": "2020-04-11T14:32:37.397890Z",
      "deliverable": true,
      "stock_amount": 1.0,
      "stock_unit": "pieces",
      "weight": 1.0,
      "weight_unit": "",
      "height": null,
      "height_unit": "",
      "length": null,
      "length_unit": "",
      "width": null,
      "width_unit": "",
      "tax_type": 1,
      "manufacturer": "Samsung",
      "active_sku": true,
      "active_short_description": true,
      "active_description": true,
      "active_effective_price": true,
      "active_dimension": true,
      "active_weight": true,
      "specification": {
        "RAM": "2GB",
        "Display size": "10inch"
      },
      "primary_category": 2,
      "images": [
        {
          "product": 1,
          "name": "try",
          "image_file": "http://eversoftgroup.ddns.net:8000/media/products/before_married_salary_after_married_salary_tVIeusG.jpg"
        },
        {
          "product": 1,
          "name": "dsa",
          "image_file": "http://eversoftgroup.ddns.net:8000/media/products/Unbenannt3.JPG"
        },
        {
          "product": 1,
          "name": "hello",
          "image_file": "http://eversoftgroup.ddns.net:8000/media/main-qimg-e93a7956e2e492201b56d11d8db867bf.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "active": true,
      "slug": "lgmob",
      "sku": "38387",
      "name": "LG Mobile",
      "price": 265.0,
      "effective_price": null,
      "price_unit": "Nepalese Rupee",
      "unit": "23",
      "short_description": "A new mobile",
      "description": "This is a new mobile of LG.",
      "for_sale": false,
      "for_sale_percent": 0.0,
      "for_sale_price": 0.0,
      "creation_date": "2020-04-15T15:14:24.583204Z",
      "deliverable": true,
      "stock_amount": 4.0,
      "stock_unit": "pieces",
      "weight": 1.0,
      "weight_unit": "",
      "height": null,
      "height_unit": "",
      "length": null,
      "length_unit": "",
      "width": null,
      "width_unit": "",
      "tax_type": 1,
      "manufacturer": "LG",
      "active_sku": true,
      "active_short_description": true,
      "active_description": true,
      "active_effective_price": true,
      "active_dimension": true,
      "active_weight": true,
      "specification": {
        "RAM": "3GB",
        "Display size": "5 inch"
      },
      "primary_category": 2,
      "images": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**component:**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Slider from "react-slick";
    import "../common/index.scss";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

    // import custom Components
    import Service from "./common/service";
    import BrandBlock from "./common/brand-block";
    import NewProduct from "../common/new-product";
    import Breadcrumb from "../common/breadcrumb";
    import DetailsWithPrice from "./common/product/details-price";
    import DetailsTopTabs from "./common/details-top-tabs";
    import { addToCart, addToCartUnsafe, addToWishlist } from "../../actions";
    import ImageZoom from "./common/product/image-zoom";
    import SmallImages from "./common/product/small-image";

    class RightSideBar extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          nav1: null,
          nav2: null,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          nav1: this.slider1,
          nav2: this.slider2,
        });
      }

      render() {
        const {
          symbol,
          item,
          addToCart,
          addToCartUnsafe,
          addToWishlist,
        } = this.props;
        console.log(item.name);
        var products = {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: false,
          arrows: true,
          fade: true,
        };
        var productsnav = {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          swipeToSlide: true,
          arrows: false,
          dots: false,
          focusOnSelect: true,
        };

        return (
          <div>
            {/* <Breadcrumb title={" Product / " + item.name} /> */}

            {/*Section Start*/}
            {item ? (
              <section className="section-b-space">
                <div className="collection-wrapper">
                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xl-12">
                              <div className="filter-main-btn mb-2">
                                <span className="filter-btn">
                                  <i
                                    className="fa fa-filter"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                  ></i>{" "}
                                  filter
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6 product-thumbnail">
                              <Slider
                                {...products}
                                asNavFor={this.state.nav2}
                                ref={(slider) => (this.slider1 = slider)}
                                className="product-slick"
                              >
                                {item.variants.map((vari, index) => (
                                  <div key={index}>
                                    <ImageZoom
                                      image={vari.images}
                                      className="img-fluid image_zoom_cls-0"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                ))}
                              </Slider>
                              <SmallImages
                                item={item}
                                settings={productsnav}
                                navOne={this.state.nav1}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <DetailsWithPrice
                              symbol={symbol}
                              item={item}
                              navOne={this.state.nav1}
                              addToCartClicked={addToCart}
                              BuynowClicked={addToCartUnsafe}
                              addToWishlistClicked={addToWishlist}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <DetailsTopTabs item={item} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-3 collection-filter">
                        {/* <BrandBlock/> */}
                        <Service />
                        {/*side-bar single product slider start*/}
                        <NewProduct />
                        {/*side-bar single product slider end*/}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            {/*Section End*/}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
      let productId = ownProps.match.params.id;
      return {
        item: state.data.products.find((el) => el.id == productId),
        symbol: state.data.symbol,
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
      addToCart,
      addToCartUnsafe,
      addToWishlist,
    })(RightSideBar);
}
```

Comment: you dont have any field called variant in your real data.

Comment: I also see an `item.variants` but no `item.variant`. Typo in question?

Comment: It's quite simple. Your test data has an array called variants (with an s), and your real data doesn't. Either add it to the real data, or check in `render` that it exists before you try to map it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to update to your render method with this

```
render() {
        const {
          symbol,
          item,
          addToCart,
          addToCartUnsafe,
          addToWishlist,
        } = this.props;
        console.log(item.name);
        var products = {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: false,
          arrows: true,
          fade: true,
        };
        var productsnav = {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          swipeToSlide: true,
          arrows: false,
          dots: false,
          focusOnSelect: true,
        };

let productVariants = [];
        if(item && item.variants && Array.isArray(item.variants) && item.variants.length > 0)
           productVariants = item.variants.map((vari, index) => (
                                  <div key={index}>
                                    <ImageZoom
                                      image={vari.images}
                                      className="img-fluid image_zoom_cls-0"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                ))}

        return (
          <div>
            {/* <Breadcrumb title={" Product / " + item.name} /> */}

            {/*Section Start*/}
            {item ? (
              <section className="section-b-space">
                <div className="collection-wrapper">
                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xl-12">
                              <div className="filter-main-btn mb-2">
                                <span className="filter-btn">
                                  <i
                                    className="fa fa-filter"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                  ></i>{" "}
                                  filter
                                </span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6 product-thumbnail">
                              <Slider
                                {...products}
                                asNavFor={this.state.nav2}
                                ref={(slider) => (this.slider1 = slider)}
                                className="product-slick"
                              >
                                {productVariants}
                              </Slider>
                              <SmallImages
                                item={item}
                                settings={productsnav}
                                navOne={this.state.nav1}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <DetailsWithPrice
                              symbol={symbol}
                              item={item}
                              navOne={this.state.nav1}
                              addToCartClicked={addToCart}
                              BuynowClicked={addToCartUnsafe}
                              addToWishlistClicked={addToWishlist}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <DetailsTopTabs item={item} />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-3 collection-filter">
                        {/* <BrandBlock/> */}
                        <Service />
                        {/*side-bar single product slider start*/}
                        <NewProduct />
                        {/*side-bar single product slider end*/}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            {/*Section End*/}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, sir for your kind support